# POST request trucated with wstring type and well formed using string

Tags: c++, string, post, wininet, wstring

I want to make a POST request using Wininet with UTF-8 special char like `€`.

```
void sendArticle()
{
    LPCWSTR browser = L"MyClientApp/1.0";
    LPCWSTR domain = L"127.0.0.1";
    LPCWSTR methode = L"POST";
    LPCWSTR page = L"/shopping/article.php";
    std::wstring strContentType = L"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";
    LPCWSTR contentType = strContentType.c_str();
    std::wstring dataStr = L"article=thecontent";
    LPVOID data = (LPVOID)dataStr.c_str();

    HINTERNET hInternet = InternetOpenW(browser, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
    HINTERNET hConnection = InternetConnectW(hInternet, domain, 80, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 1);
    HINTERNET hRequest  = HttpOpenRequestW(hConnection, methode, page, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 1);
    HttpSendRequestW(hRequest, contentType, strContentType.size(), data, dataStr.size());
}
```

If I use string type for variable `dataStr`, the content is sent correctly. If I use wstring type for the variable (to send UTF-8 content), the request is truncated.
I can observe TCP packet using Wireshark.
To resume, this line `std::string dataStr = "article=thecontent";` works but this line `std::wstring dataStr = L"article=thecontent";` not works.
I checked the int returned by `size()` method and it's correct. What is this strange phenomenon and how to solve it ?

Comment: According to the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wininet/nf-wininet-httpsendrequestw), the last parameter of `HttpSendRequestW` is the number of *bytes*, not the number of characters.  Try `dataStr.size() * sizeof(WCHAR);`

Answer (score 0):

HttpSendRequestW takes a *size in bytes* for the data size parameter but you are using wide strings so you really want:

```
HttpSendRequestW(hRequest, contentType, strContentType.size(), data, sizeof(WCHAR)*dataStr.size());
```

However, http really works properly using utf8 so sending utf16 is kinda weird (although as you can interpret the data-payload however you wish so sending utf16 is ok I guess).

What you really want to do is just send utf8 anyway - which you can do using narrow strings - just make dataStr a std::string and fill it with utf8 code points and you're good.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, indeed I just want to send special char like `€` or `é`, `à`... Could you help me to have a proper code ?

Comment: @ejeqaddoj-6455: std::string dataStr = u8"€"; Then leave everything else the same.

Comment: Hey, I am interesting by your answer but the problem is the same. Could you post a "turnkey" solution ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The server expects UTF8 data (`dataStr`), so data must be converted from UTF16 to UTF8. Keep everything else in wide char format, as those functions are properly handled by wide string APIs

```
//convert dataStr to UTF8
int sz = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, dataStr.c_str(), -1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
std::string utf8(sz, 0);
WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, dataStr.c_str(), (int)dataStr.size(), &utf8[0], sz, 0, 0);

//send UTF8 data
HttpSendRequestW(hRequest, contentType, strContentType.size(), utf8.data(), utf8.size());
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in place of using wstring and convert it to UTF-8, it's not more logical to use string and send it normally as UTF-8 content ? Could you help me to convert the code ? Thanks.

Comment: use `u8"string"`

Comment: Hey, I am interesting by your answer but the problem is the same. Could you post a "turnkey" solution ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this is the solution I found and it works perfectlly :

```
void sendHello()
{
    LPCSTR header = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";
    std::string dataStr = u8"message=ééàà€€";
    LPVOID myMessage = (LPVOID)dataStr.c_str();
    HINTERNET hInternet = InternetOpenA("InetURL/1.0", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
    HINTERNET hConnection = InternetConnectA(hInternet, "127.0.0.1", 80, " ", " ", INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 1);
    HINTERNET hRequest = HttpOpenRequestA(hConnection, "POST", "/SendMessage.php", NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 1);
    HttpSendRequestA(hRequest, header, strlen(header), myMessage, dataStr.size());
}
```